# How to update source bind when target's property changes?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I've got two text boxes `txt1` and `txt2` and a string dependency property `sprop`.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty spropProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("sprop", typeof (string), typeof (MainWindow), new UIPropertyMetadata(string.Empty));

public string sprop
{
    get { return (string) this.GetValue(spropProperty); }
    set { this.SetValue(spropProperty, value); }
}
```

Now, if I set data binding in XAML for `txt1` this way:

```
Text="{Binding sprop, ElementName=window, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}
```

`txt1` updates `sprop` instantaneously, whenever the text box text is changed.

But if I set data binding in C# for `txt2` this way:

```
DataContext = this;
txt2.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, "sprop");
```

then `txt2` updates `sprop` only when it loses focus.

**How can I update `sprop` as soon as `txt2`'s text changes using C# code?**

---

What I have tried:

```
DataContext = this;
var myBinding = new Binding("sprop");
myBinding.Source = this;
myBinding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
txt2.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, myBinding);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to also set the UpdateSourceTrigger in your txt2 in order to get updated once property changed, which you can also set in code:

```
Binding myBinding = new Binding("MyDataProperty");
myBinding.Source = myDataObject;
myBinding.Mode = TwoWay;
myBinding.UpdateSourceTrigger = PropertyChanged;
myText.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, myBinding);
```

Comment: According to your suggestion I have tried the code that I added at the end of my edited question, but it doesn't work. Could you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @IneedHelp See the edit as licabl suggest, see also http://csharpsimplified.wordpress.com/2009/08/22/updatesourcetrigger-databinding/ for detailed instructions.

Comment: Heh, seems the problem ws that I copied the example with `TextBlock` and I needed to use `TextBox`.

Answer (score 1):

Did you set the txt2 to Mode=TwoWay?